# Do I need a visa for Zurich, if my connecting flight stops for 24 hours in Zurich?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, h1b-visas, western-europe

Do I need visa for Switzerland, if my connecting flight stops at Zurich for 22hrs and I want to visit Zurich during those 22 hrs? I have US H1-B visa. I'll be travelling from Minneapolis to Mumbai (India) via Zurich. I hold an Indian passport. Also while returning back, I have a halt in Vienna for 16 hours.

What type of Schengen VISA would I need and what is the procedure for that visa?